# RESTful webservice in iphone

Tags: iphone

How can i use Restful webservice in iphone instead of soap?

Comment: It has been asked many times before. Search on stackoverflow before you post a question. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110817/iphone-dealing-with-xml-vs-soap-vs-json-vs-restful  OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908560/developing-restful-website-and-iphone-and-possibly-other-smart-phones-applicati and many more ... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=restful+webservice+iphone

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend searching for the possible answers to your question on Stackoverflow first. But one specific answer to using a REST base webservice. I highly recommend [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). They have a very easy method for retrieving data from a service. I have used the code in quite a few apps that needed to access webservices.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request startSynchronous];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
    NSString *response = [request responseString];
}
```

Comment: is this method enough to receive data from service?
what library files should i import to use ASIHTTPRequest?

Comment: Yes, the `response` variable will contain the data back from the service. Go to http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions  and download their files and then copy them in following the instructions.

Comment: Hello, i m new to ios, so any one have working example to of calling and parsing restfull webservice